# [Unity]Is there a way that i can post http request when executing unity editor and after closing it?

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine

I want to post `System.Environment.UserName` to a database with a "status" when opening and closing unity! Not when playing a scene.
When opening unity, I want to update 'ON' status and when closing 'OFF' status or 1 and 0 in database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though your question is quite broad ...

---

**Yes there is!**

You can use the `UnityWebRequest` in a way you *usually wouldn't*: Without a Coroutine. During opening the editor and closing it probably is not that bad if there is a short delay during the web request so we can use a simple blocking call in this specific use case.

So simply wait for it to finish in a usual `while` loop. I just created an example using a simple [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) to some random images on Google but you can easily replace it with any more complex [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html).

Simply start the Open request via [`InitializeOnLoadMethod`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) and also register a callback to [`EditorApplication.wantsToQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-wantsToQuit.html) in order to call the close request when the Unity is tried to be closed. This way the Editor can only be closed if the callback for `EditorApplication.wantsToQuit` returned `true`.

**Make sure to put this file into a folder called `Editor`.**

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public static class Example
{
    // InitializeOnLoadMethod causes this method to be called when the editor is opened
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Initialize()
    {
        #region Required Part
        // register callback
        // The editor will only close if OnQuitEditor returns true
        EditorApplication.wantsToQuit += OnQuitEditor;

        // I'll just do a random Get Request but you can do any request here
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/2000px-Example.svg.png");

        request.SendWebRequest();

        while (!request.isDone && !request.isHttpError && !request.isNetworkError)
        {
            // just wait
        } 

        if(request.isHttpError || request.isNetworkError || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.error))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Couldn't finish opening request!");
            return;
        }    
        #endregion Required Part

        #region DEMO Part
        // Just to show here that it worked create a file called "Open"
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "open.txt");
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);

        using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                writer.Write("Hello!");
            }
        }
        #endregion DEMO Part
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hinders the Editor to close if the request failed
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool OnQuitEditor()
    {
        #region Required Part
        // I'll just do a random Get Request but you can do any request here
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-red-square-grunge-stamp-260nw-327662909.jpg");

        request.SendWebRequest();

        while (!request.isDone && !request.isHttpError && !request.isNetworkError)
        {
            // just wait
        }

        if(request.isHttpError || request.isNetworkError || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.error))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Couldn't finish closing request!");
            return false;
        }    
        #endregion Required Part

        #region DEMO Part
        // Just to show here that it worked delete the Open file and create a closed file
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);

        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "open.txt");
        if(File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);

        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "close.txt");

        using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                writer.Write("World!");
            }
        }
        #endregion DEMO Part

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.error);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Currently the editor could not be closed in the usual way in case the closing request fails so you might adjust this to your needs. If e.g. the result of the closing request is not that important you could rather add a simple `void` as callback to [`EditorApplication.quitting`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-quitting.html) instead.

---

As a little demo that it works here you can see that when I open the project the `Assets/StreamingAssets/open.txt` is created.

When I close the project the `Assets/StreamingAssets/open.txt` is deleted and the `Assets/StreamingAssets/closed.txt` created instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the editor script here that will help you with the load editor.

[Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup {
    static Startup()
    {
        Debug.Log("Up and running");
    }
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers aren't welcome, because a link can be dead in the futur. Please add content from that link

Comment: but how can i run a UnityWebRequest on a static method?

Comment: but i get "cannot access non static method in a static context"  and also i cannot  use "StartCoroutine" because it need MonoBehavior

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is to use a script that launches Unity and perform the HTTP Posts requests.

In example, in powershell :

```bsh
# Post to an url the params
$postParams = @{username=$Env:UserName;status='ON'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com -Method POST -Body $postParams

# Start Unity and wait it's closed
Start-Process $pathToUnityExecutable -Wait

# Post the new status
$postParams = @{username=$Env:UserName;status='OFF'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux though ;) I would prefer the Unity built-in way

Comment: @derHugo I agree, your solution is better than mine. Powershell was just an example, I'm sure the same can be done in shell